# unrelated t-test and normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, t-test

sorry a bit of a long question here and would appreciate some clarity.
so everyone on my psychology course seems to be disagreeing on which statistical test to use for this practical report and now i'm a little lost on whether i chose the right test for the data. for this practical, people were randomly assigned to one of two groups, which affected the sentence structure of some of the statements on the survey and then completed an online survey where they could either select "yes" or "no" to verify the truth of anomalous and truthful statements.
so this means the data is at a nominal level. we were looking for a difference between the two groups, hypothesising that one group would give a greater number of "yes" answers to anomalous statements.
[image: flowchart]

so using this flowchart, i assumed using the unrelated t-test would be correct as the data, the number of "yes" responses, out of 11 is interval. but using the unrelated t-test means you assume the data is from a normally distributed population.

we use SPSS to analyse the data and in my computing class last semester, on the week where we performed unrelated t-tests on the given data at the time, the histograms produced looked like this:
[image: unrelated t test distributions]
if i'm not wrong, the distributions here look slightly skewed but they're taken as normal?

using SPSS, the histograms produced from the current practical data looked like this:
[image: distribution for 'focused' group]
[image: distribution for 'unfocused' group]

and now people on my course seem to be disagreeing about whether it counts as a normal distribution because they both appear slightly skewed, but not substantially? does it need to be exactly normal?
so some people think the unrelated t-test is the right one to use, others say we should use mann-whitney U and some think we should use ANOVA. i would like a second opinion on whether i'm using the right statistical test and whether the distribution is normal, thank you!